# Moving ASP.Net System.Net.Mail settings to Web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, web-config, settings

We are using this coding to send email from an ASP.Net code-behind Vb.Net file.

Can any of this coding be placed inside the Web.config file?

```
Protected Sub EmailStudentList()

    ' Get the rendered HTML.
    '-----------------------
    Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
    Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
    Dim htmlTW As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)

    GridViewSummary.RenderControl(htmlTW)

    ' Get the HTML into a string.
    ' This will be used in the body of the email report.
    '---------------------------------------------------
    Dim dataGridHTML As String = SB.ToString()

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ourEmailUsername@gmail.com", "ourPassword")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

    ObjMailMessage = New MailMessage()

    Try
        ObjMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("ourEmail@gmail.com", "Some text is here.", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        ObjMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("BoardOfDirectors@gmail.com", "Emad-ud-deen", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        ObjMailMessage.Subject = "List of enrolled students for the board of directors"
        ObjMailMessage.Body = dataGridHTML
        ObjMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
        ObjMailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure

        SmtpServer.Send(ObjMailMessage)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="ourEmail@gmail.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" 
             userName="ourEmailUsername@gmail.com" 
             password="ourPassword" 
             host="smtp.gmail.com" 
             enableSsl="true" 
             port="587"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick reply! Very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't place "code" in your config file but you can move a number of the settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Looks like we both landed on the same answer which is reassuring.

Answer (score 2):

I have put some of these items in web.config`.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="<<Host IP Address>>" port="<<Host Port Number>>" userName="" password=""/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
        <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

The following link may help as well:

[Element (Network Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w355a94k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)